# Polymer dom binding to attribute

Tags: polymer

I have this auto-binding template:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[row]]" as="item">
  <td violated=[[item.violated]] class="result-tb-data">[[item.value]]</td>
</template>
```

I don't know why `item.value` is binded correctly but `[[item.violated]]` is not binded. The value exists because I have tried the reverse binding:

```
<td violated=[[item.value]] class="result-tb-data">[[item.violated]]</td>
```

I know that it is not binded because I have this style:

```
.result-tb-data[violated=true] {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

and `item.violated` is a boolean field.

Here is a full example:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <style>
    span[violated="true"] {
      font-style: italic;
    }
  </style>

  <template>
    <span violated="{{violated}}">Text</span>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
    properties: {
      violated: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: true
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for binding to attribute contains a `$` ([docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding)). So in your case it should be:

```
violated$=[[item.violated]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maria is correct, but when I tried your example I came across another problem.

This is you're setting a boolean to a property and not a string. This works:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <style>   
    span[violated="true"] {
      font-style: italic; 
    }       
  </style>  

  <template>    
    <span violated$="{{violated}}">Text</span>
  </template>   
</dom-module>

<script>  
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
    properties: {   
      violated: {
        type: String,
        value: "true" 
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You could also keep `violated` as a `Boolean` and remove `="true"` in the style.